# Can't get the wireless adapter to work, any workarounds?

Tags: wireless, adapter

I have a currently unsupported wireless usb adapter TL-WN8200ND, and I can not get it to work on Ubuntu.

I was wondering whether it was possible to get it to work using an older versions driver with some modifications or some other methodology in general ?

edit : it is a TP-Link product with no driver support for a linux environment

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is an Realtek RTL8192CU type device. You should be able to download Linux drivers for it from their [driver download page](http://www.realtek.com.tw/downloads/downloadsView.aspx?Langid=1&PFid=48&Level=5&Conn=4&ProdID=277&DownTypeID=3&GetDown=false&Downloads=true).

Comment: it is a TP-Link product with no driver support for a linux environment

Comment: @Pumpkin: I understand that it's a TP-Link product and that TP-Link do not provide drivers for anything other than Windows. However inside the plastic cover is, I believe, a Realtek RTL8192CU implementation. Realtek do actually provide Unix and Linux drivers for most of their chipsets. Provided that TP-Link hasn't drastically modified the implementation there is a good chance that the Realtek drivers will work. Good luck!